# Only one reducer is being recognized in my reducer tree/state in my redux dev tools

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

Hi I am new to redux and I'm having trouble seeing my entire tree of reducers, so far I only see the getTopGames reducer in my redux dev tools and I cant figure out why I can't see anything else like shop, and getGameDetails. Since I set up my store and combined all my reducers shouldn't I see all the reducer states in my devtools? (Ex. getTopGames, under that shop, under that getGameDetails)??? Thank you for any help and insight here is the github link https://github.com/andrewjkim745/Twitch-Store  [image: this is my devtools]

[image]

[image][image: This is where I define my store]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in `INITIAL_STATE` you've only define `getTopGames` reducer.

[image]

That's why initially you can only see the `getTopGames` reducer in your redux dev tools. Add your other reducers `shop` and `getGameDetails` in `INITIAL_STATE` then you'll be able to see them initially in your redux dev tools. Even if you don't, once you start performing actions from other reducers, you can see them in your redux dev tools.

Comment: Thank you this was it! can't believe I missed that!

Comment: ok got it thanks again!